# JRE or JDK issue and eclipse cannot be run

Tags: java, eclipse

A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Develpoment Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:

C:/Program Files/Java/jre-10.01/bin

Everything was fine and then few days ago I got an update for java after that this began to show up. I found on internet solution about going into advanced system settings and changing path but it didn't help. 
Does JDK and JRE have to be same version, in my case, JRE is 10.0.2 and JDK is 9.0.4?

[image]

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Older versions won't run with Java 10 (or 9)

Comment: I think it was updated to last one, Photon, or smth like that

Comment: Check if the 'eclipse.ini' file specifies the Java location using `-vm`. If it does change it to the correct location.

Comment: You don't need both. The JDK is a superset of the JRE and contains everything the JRE has along with tools such as compilers, debuggers, etc. What you want to install is the JDK in your case. Then make sure your path variable is right, and that the path is correct in Eclipse as well.

Comment: I found the solution, after update it was changed to jre-10.0.2 from 10.0.1, changed in eclipse file, thanks for responses